# Microsoft-Account authentication issues after Office365 organization join

Tags: microsoft-office-365, outlook, entra-id, single-sign-on, autodiscover

Years ago I registered my domain for **Windows Live Domains (domains.live.com)** and created 5 accounts for me and my family (`@mydomain.tld`). These email-adresses are our primary addresses and also Microsoft-Accounts that we use to login on our PCs, bought apps in the store and so on. Back in 2014 Microsoft decided to close this service but everything continued working and I actually never thought about changing it as long as I could receive and send emails.

About 4 months ago my personal Microsoft-Account got added to a friends **Office365-business organization** (as an external account so *#EXT#*) and since then I am having troubles with my account. Since then whenever I login at Microsoft services I, understandably, have to select whether to log in using my personal or my school/work/... account.

First thing I noticed was that my phone (using Android + Nine app) would **no longer sync emails/contacts/...**. Also reconnecting always resulted in an error. Since then I could not add my email-address to the Outlook-Desktop app anymore. It wouldn't ask for personal/business account and (seems to) always authenticate against the business account.

I got my account **disconnected** from my friends Office365 and also confirmed that it was not in the recycle bin. Still the selection between personal and school/work account did NOT disapear. Also after waiting another month, because I thought maybe it needs some time to sync, nothing changed.

What works:

- Outlook desktop accounts BEFORE the add (for all `@mydomain.tld`)
- Outlook mobile app
- Windows Mail app
- Nine app (for everyonle else but me - `@mydomain.tld`)
- Receiving and sending Emails via Outlook.com

What I already tried:

- Microsoft Support: 3 hours of teamviewer trying to set up Outlook, never checked why there was a business account where there should be none :(
- I can see from various tests that AutoDiscover is working for other account on my domain, while for my account it does not (Nine logs + Outlook AutoDisover tester)

I am pretty sure that something in Microsofts Cloud setup was overwritten when adding my account to the O365 organization. My domain was somehow pointed to Office365-Business instead of Outlook.com and for my personal account there are some settings that weren't reverted/removed when I was removed from O365.

Does anyone have experienced similiar problems? Can I even solve this problem on my own?
Does someone have a better Microsoft Support contact? I was on-line with the business support which said they can't help me until I have a business account with my domain (which would definitly ruin the current setup for all my family members)

I've played with the idea of setting up the "new" premium features of using your own domain for your Microsoft Account. But I fear it would not correct the issues in the backend system of Microsoft. Does someone have experiences with that?